# A question about linearly independent monomorphisms.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, monomorphisms

My question was too big to put it in the title:

Having a set of linearly independent field monomorphisms $K→L$, is it still possible to express one of these monomorphisms as a linear combination of the others, only that the coefficients could vary depending on which element of $K$ we pick?

---

Say we have a set of $n$ independent field monomorphisms $K→L$, that is, the only way for $$c_1m_1(x)+c_2m_2(x)+...+c_nm_n(x)=0 $$ for all $x$ in $K$ is for all the $c_i$ to be zero.

But I was wondering, in contrast to vectors, is it still possible to express one of these monomorphisms, say $m_1(x)$, as a linear combination of the others?

To better explain myself, wouldn't it be possible for some fields $K$ to be divisible into two sets of elements, say $A$ and $B$, and then

$$m_1(a)=r_2m_2(a)+...+r_nm_n(a)$$ for all $a$ in $A$, and

$$m_1(b)=s_2m_2(b)+...+s_nm_n(b)$$ for all $b$ in $B$.

Notice that this doesn't contradict (at least for what I can see), the fact that the set of monomorphisms is linearly independent.

---

I would really appreciate any help/thoughts

Comment: Your question and notations are unclear. For $L/K$ a finite extension, $L$ is a $n=[L:K]$-dimensional $K$-vector space, thus $Aut(L/K) = \{ \sigma_j \}$ is a finite group of inversible $K$-linear maps $L \to L$. The normal basis theorem is that for $L/K$ Galois, $Disc(L/K) \ne 0$, thus the $\sigma_j$ are $K$-linearly independent, as linear maps. Fixing a basis of $L/K$, the $\sigma_j$ are just matrices $\in K^{n \times n}$.

Comment: Given $n > 1$ elements $m_i$ of the field $L$, it is *always* possible to find elements $c_i$ not all zero such that $\sum c_im_i = 0$, In fact, there is an $n-1$ dimensional space of such $(c_i)$. It does not matter if those $m_i$ happen to be the images of some $x$ under monomorphisms or not. Independence only becomes a useful concept when the same $c_i$ has to work for many related different values of the $m_i$. For example, when the $m_i = m_i(x)$ are monomorphisms, and we need those $c_i$ to hold for all values of $x$, not just one.